# Failed to apply kotlin-android

Tags: flutter, dart

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quZQi.jpg)

I been trying to run flutter using emulator but I couldn't do because it throws me a error like

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:

Build file 'C:\Users\SANO\test\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25

• What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating project ¹:app'. > Failed to apply plugin 'kotlin-android".

> Could not create an instance of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinAndroidProject Extension. > Could not generate a decorated class for type KotlinAndroidProjectExtension. > org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/KotlinTarget

. Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with info or-debug option to get more log output. Run wi th--scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 Exited (sigterm)

Comment: Please try this solution. possibly same question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63314023/getting-failed-to-apply-plugin-id-kotlin-android-when-trying-flutter-hello