# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. (flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

im trying to clone project, im fixing the android embedding problem, etc. and im facing this problem.

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\muham\OneDrive\Documents\KP\sipintar-enterprise-mobile-dev_upgrade\sipintar-enterprise-mobile-dev_upgrade\sipintar-enterprise-mobile-dev_upgrade\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> org/gradle/api/services/BuildService

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`

---

this is build.gradle line 25

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

pls help me im new at this

Comment: try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63314023/getting-failed-to-apply-plugin-id-kotlin-android-when-trying-flutter-hello

Comment: i try it but its still the same error